# Trying to get all numbers sum form an array by map() method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

At first I have have made a normal function to get the sum of the array elements [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] and it works I got 45 as output.. After that I have tried the same logic with map() method, so that I can put the sum result in an array. but in the map() method instead of giving me the sum of the all array elements its gave me this output [1,3,5,7,9,11,13].If I made any mistake to build the logic, could you please explain me to get the addition of array elements what would be the logic if I want to use map() method. below I attached the code.

```
//normal function to get the sum of array numbers

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

      function add(nums) {
            let sum = 0;

        for (const num of nums) {
            sum = sum + num;
      }
            return sum;
}
```

console.log(add(array));

```
//map() method

const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

let add = numbers.map((num, sum = 0) => sum = sum + num);

console.log(add);
```

Comment: *"Trying to get all numbers sum form an array by map() method"* `map` is just fundamentally the wrong method for this. Use a loop (directly, or hidden away in a call to `reduce`), but `map` makes no more sense than `filter` for an operation that doesn't create a new array with mapped elements.

Comment: .reduce() method easier way to sum elements inside an array and you can do it in a single line of code

Answer (score 7):

You can't sum with `map`. `map` always returns a new array with the same length.

You wanted to use `reduce`

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const result = numbers.reduce((sum, num) => sum + num);
console.log(result);
```

As [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) suggested in the comment, skipping the second argument can lead to a failure if the array is empty

```js
const numbers = [];
const result = numbers.reduce((sum, num) => sum + num);
console.log(result);
```

So it's better to use it if you can

```js
const numbers = [];
const result = numbers.reduce((sum, num) => sum + num, 0);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Well, you *can* do it with `sum`, but only by [misusing `map`](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/) *(disclosure: that's my article)*. So you shouldn't. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder nice article,  the misusage of map bothers me as well